# Create a dataframe from a hashmap with keys as column names and values as rows in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and I have a column which is a map in dataframe like this -

```
scala> df.printSchema
```

```
root
 |-- A1: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

I need to select all the keys from dataframe as column name and values as rows.

For eg:
Let say I have 2 records like this-

```
1. key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2, key3 -> value3 ....
2. key1 -> value11, key3 -> value13, key4 -> value14 ...
```

I want the output dataframe as

```
key1             key2                 key3             key4
value1           value2               value3            null
value11          null                 value13           value14
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First we need to create an `id` column by which we can group your data, then `explode` the map column `A1`, and finally reshape your `df` using `pivot()`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{monotonically_increasing_id, explode, first}

df.withColumn("id", (monotonically_increasing_id()))
  .select($"id", explode($"A1"))
  .groupBy("id")
  .pivot("key")
  .agg(first("value")).show()
+---+-------+------+-------+-------+
| id|   key1|  key2|   key3|   key4|
+---+-------+------+-------+-------+
|  0| value1|value2| value3|   null|
|  1|value11|  null|value13|value14|
+---+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Hey,  When i try to run this, i m getting below error-                                error: value pivot is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData      Do you have any idea which import statement would work?

Comment: what spark version do you use?

Comment: i was able to get this with spark version 2.1. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that column with the `Map` is named "my_map"

1. Get set of unique keys (skip this step if you already has the keys beforehand):

```
val keys = df
  .select(explode(expr("map_keys(my_map)")).as("keys_to_rows"))
  .agg(collect_set("keys_to_rows"))
  .collect()
  .head.getSeq[String](0)
```

2. Select map values by keys as a columns:

```
df.select(
  keys.map(key => col(s"B.$key").as(key)): _*
)
```